# ifelse statement based on multiple characters as conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, machine-learning, gbm

I have the following function:

```
brt <- gbm.step(data = train,
                          gbm.x = 5:9, # column indices for covariates
                          gbm.y = 4, # column index for response (presence-absence)
                          family = "bernoulli",
                          tree.complexity = ifelse(prNum < 50, 1, 5),
                          learning.rate = 0.001,
                          bag.fraction = 0.75,
                          max.trees = ifelse(s == "Jacaranda.puberula" | s == "Cestrum.intermedium", 50, 10000),
                          n.trees = 50,
                          n.folds = 5, # 5-fold cross-validation
                          silent = TRUE) # avoid printing the cv results
```

I'm trying to run the abovementioned function but they way I'm using the `ifelse` inside the `max.trees` argument returns an error. Is that the right way of coding it? What I'm trying to accomplish is simply using 50, instead of 10000 `max.trees` for those two species: *Jacaranda.puberula* or *Cestrum.intermedium*. Just to inform, the object `s` comes from another vector called `sp`, which is a list of species names. Each `s` is a different species that I'm looping in this function.

Is the problem on the way I am writing the statement or in the fact that I'm using OR as the logical?

EDIT: I think that may be something related to the function. I re-runned the analysis here and it returns:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") :
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized Boosted Regression Trees (`gbm`) does not seem to have any `max.trees` hyperparameter, you can use the condition for the hyperparameter `n.trees` instead, which works (or do you mean `max_depth`)?

`n.trees = ifelse(s == "Jacaranda.puberula" | s == "Cestrum.intermedium", 50, 10000)`

EDIT:

Without having access to your data, it's difficult to guess exactly what is going wrong. Last time I assumed that package you used is `gbm`. However, with a sample dataset (`BostonHousing` from the package `mlbench`), the below example shows how the `gbm` implementations from both the `gbm` and `dismo` packages work as expected:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
head(BostonHousing)
# crim zn indus chas   nox    rm  age    dis rad tax ptratio      b lstat medv
#1 0.00632 18  2.31    0 0.538 6.575 65.2 4.0900   1 296    15.3 396.90  4.98 24.0
#2 0.02731  0  7.07    0 0.469 6.421 78.9 4.9671   2 242    17.8 396.90  9.14 21.6
#3 0.02729  0  7.07    0 0.469 7.185 61.1 4.9671   2 242    17.8 392.83  4.03 34.7
#4 0.03237  0  2.18    0 0.458 6.998 45.8 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.63  2.94 33.4
#5 0.06905  0  2.18    0 0.458 7.147 54.2 6.0622   3 222    18.7 396.90  5.33 36.2
#6 0.02985  0  2.18    0 0.458 6.430 58.7 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.12  5.21 28.7

library(gbm)
set.seed(102) # for reproducibility
# predict target medv given other predictors
gbm1 <- gbm(medv ~ ., data = BostonHousing, #var.monotone = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            distribution = "gaussian", shrinkage = 0.1,
            n.trees = 100,
            interaction.depth = 3, bag.fraction = 0.5, train.fraction = 0.5,
            n.minobsinnode = 10, cv.folds = 5, keep.data = TRUE,
            verbose = FALSE, n.cores = 1)
#predict(gbm1)

library(dismo)
# predict target medv given other predictors
gbm2 <- gbm.step(data=BostonHousing, gbm.x = 1:13, gbm.y = 14, family = "gaussian",
                            max.trees = 10000,
                            tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5)



#predict(gbm2)

# compare predictions
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(index=1:nrow(BostonHousing),
           actual=BostonHousing$medv, 
           pred.gbm1=predict(gbm1), 
           pred.gbm2=predict(gbm2)) %>% 
  gather('pred', 'medv', -index) %>%
  ggplot(aes(index, medv, group=pred, color=pred)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I think that's because I'm using the `gbm.step` function from `dismo` package. In the package, the `gbm.step` function has n.trees = initial number of trees, max.trees = max number of trees to fit before stopping. The `max.trees` may be a wrapper around `max_depth`, I think?

Comment: I may try to tweek the `n.trees` hyperparameter too. I'm re-running the function here so I can post the exact error I'm having.

Comment: Hi, I edited the original post. Could you take a look? Now it happened in another `s`. I think is returning NULL because it is unable to fit an x number of trees...I really don't know. I haven't found a solution in the GitHub too. Should I re-post this question in another "section"?

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know what happened here but it eventually worked (and I changed absolutely nothing, really).

Comment: actually, I did something: my `max.trees` parameter was changed to 1000 and `n.trees` (the starting number of trees) was changed to 10. I'm still not sure what happened but definitely it has something to do with these parameters.